# Using Switch statements on Sets (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

```
enum RepeatDay : String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Monday = "Monday"
    case Tuesday = "Tuesday"
    case Wednesday = "Wednesday"
    case Thursday = "Thursday"
    case Friday = "Friday"
    case Saturday = "Saturday"
    case Sunday = "Sunday"

    var description : String { return rawValue }

    static let allValues = [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]
}
```

The above is declared in my model. This would be a similar use case like the day selection in the stock Clock app while setting up an alarm.

But the below complains!!

```
            guard let repeatDay = $0 else { return "" }
            switch repeatDay {
            case .Monday :
                break
            default:
                break
            }
```

[image: screenshot]

where `repeatDay` is a Set, as indicated in the above screenshot.

Is there a way of using switch statement in this scenario? Any alternatives are welcome.

Comment: Give us more context about the declaration of `repeatDay`

Comment: BTW, when your enum has a `String` draw value, it's default raw values are set to the case names, so you can write just `case Monday` instead of `case Monday = "Monday"`

Comment: Oh, okay. But what I expect as I've told is to be able to abbreviate when the days are selected to 'Mon', 'Tue' respectively and to have 'weekdays', if all the five weekdays are selected.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, I guess there isn't much to explain about `RepeatDay`. I have it all posted in the above question.

Comment: I don't understand your first comment, could you elaborate please?

Comment: In the stock Clock app, while setting up an alarm and choosing the repeat days, as we select the days, they aren't displayed completely, but abbreviated. Monday to Mon, Tuesday to Tue and so on. But when we select only Saturday or Sunday, we are shown "Weekends" and if all the weekdays have been selected, we are shown "Weekdays"..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127141/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-shyam).

Comment: It's a bad idea to hardcode the names of the weekdays. `DateFormatter` has several properties for getting full and abbreviated weekday names based on the user's locale.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you.. I am looking at Alexander's solution. Seems to be spot on for what I'm looking..

Answer (score 1):

You're switching on a `Set<RepeatDay>`, but the case is a `RepeatDay`. The switch statement has no way of knowing how you expect it to handle those different types.

I suspect you're trying to match particular types of sets of days, such as the set of days that are week days, and the set of days are weekends. In this case, your switch's case statements need to be `Set<RepeatDay`, which can be compared to the provided `Set<RepeatDay>`.

```
switch days {
    case [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday, .Friday]:
        print("Weekdays")
    case [.Saturday, .Sunday]:
        print("Weekends")
    default:
        print(days)
}
```

I would extract those case statements' Sets into being static members of the `Day` enum, and add some more logic for describing consecutive intervals of days. You can also obtain the locale-accurate names for days from the [`weekdaySymbols`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter/1412405-weekdaysymbols) of [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter)

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger {
    func isConsecutive() -> Bool {
        zip(self, self.dropFirst()).allSatisfy { current, next in
            current + 1 == next
        }
    }
}

enum Day: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Sunday
    case Monday
    case Tuesday
    case Wednesday
    case Thursday
    case Friday
    case Saturday
    
    /*TODO: Note that this stores the weekdaySymbols permanently once
    the app is launched. If there is a change in locale after the app
    launch, then the days will not be updated. If this is a concern,
    this `DayNames` constant should be deleted, and all references
    to it should be changed to DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols, which
    will dynamically obtain the weekdays accurate to the current locale */
    static let DayNames: [String] = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols
    
    public var description: String { return Day.DayNames[self.rawValue] }
    
    static let Everyday: Set<Day> = [.Sunday, .Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday, .Friday, .Saturday]
    static let Weekdays: Set<Day> = [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday, .Friday]
    static let Weekends: Set<Day> = [.Saturday, .Sunday]
    
    

    static func describeDays(_ days: Set<Day>) -> String {
        guard !days.isEmpty else { return "No days" }
        
        switch days { // Predefined cases
            case Day.Everyday: return "Everyday"
            case Day.Weekdays: return "Weekdays"
            case Day.Weekends: return "Weekends"
            default: break
        }
        
        let array = days.map{ $0.rawValue }.sorted()
        
        switch array {
            case _ where array.isConsecutive(): // Consecutive range of days
                let min = array.first!
                let max = array.last!
                return "\(Day(rawValue: min)!) - \(Day(rawValue: max)!)"
            default: return days.description //arbitrary days
        }
    }
}

print(Day.describeDays(Day.Everyday))
print(Day.describeDays(Day.Weekdays))
print(Day.describeDays(Day.Weekends))
print(Day.describeDays([.Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday])) // Monday - Thursday
print(Day.describeDays([.Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Thursday, .Saturday])) //[Saturday, Wednesday, Thursday, Tuesday]
```

[You can see this in action, here.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/581981d3e94690139f8ba55b)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
guard let repeatDay = RepeatDay(rawValue: $0) else { return "" }
    switch repeatDay {
    case .Monday :
        break
    default:
        break
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of $0 in your closure is not `RepeatDay` but `Set<RepeatDay>`,try  this:

```
guard let repeatDay = $0.first else { return "" }
    switch repeatDay {
    case .Monday :
        break
    default:
        break
    }
```